# Will apps exempted from background optimization be affected by low-battery triggered energy saving?

Tags: applications, battery-life, lineageos, background-data, background-process

I disabled optimization for Whatsapp. I want to limit Whatsapp only if the battery is low.

Does LineageOs 14 ignore the whitelist on low battery out of the box already?

I'm wondering about this because Whatsapp Web reads 'phone not connected' too much freqently on wifi and I disabled optimizations, as a countermeasure (yet it does not seem to be working)... despite that I'm curious about android and lineageos behaviour regarding this.